# Indirect question set off by comma

Tags: commas, indirect-question

"Will things ever be the same, is the question most people have."

Is the above phrasing correct? The first part of the sentence is an indirect question, but I cannot find anything in *Chicago* that instructs how to punctuate the indirect question if another part of the sentence follows it.

Answer (score -1):

The part before the comma is not an indirect question. A subordinate closed interrogative (which I assume is what is meant by *indirect qurestion*) would start with subordinators *whether* or *if* and is not separated from the verb *is* by a comma:

> Whether things will ever be the same is the question most people have.
>
> If things will ever be the same is the question most people have.

If you're intent on using a main clause interrogative as in the example given, you'd have to put quote marks around it and there still would be no comma required:

> "Will things ever be the same?" is the question most people have.